# Передача значения переменной через несколько страниц

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Прошу совета, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать отправку значения переменной. С начало из формы на странице *index.php* передаем, методом **POST** или **GET** не важно, на страницу *connect.php* переменную например **$id**, далее со странице *connect.php* передаем эту же переменную **$id** на третью страницу например *getUser.php*. Ну т.е. надо, чтобы эта переменная постоянно следовала по страницам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да.

```
index.php

$_SESSION['data']=$_GET['data'];

connect.php

$mydata=$_SESSION['data'];

getUser.php

$mydata=$_SESSION['data'];
//данные больше не нужны
unset($_SESSION['data']);
```

Comment: @Arc уффффф.... Огромное спасибо :)

Comment: а не за что :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Можно эти параметры заносить в БД или в сессии в php, по определенному ключу, и как только дойдет до страницы добавления, необходимо их достать
2. При генерации очередной страницы, добавляем данные, с предыдущих страниц

Comment: @IVsevolod спасибо за помощь, смотрите какой принцип, первая страница это отправка переменной через форму, далее на второй странице идет перенаправление на другую страницу через функцию header();, может быть мне в заголовке как-то передать эту переменную? Вы наверное правильно говорите, это надо сделать через сессии, у меня как раз там идет начало сессии.

Comment: GET?

$mydata = 'username';
header('Location: http://www.example.com/page.php?mydata=' . $mydata);

Comment: @Олег Б спасибо!